# JOptionPane.showMessageDialog is not working on tomcat

Tags: joptionpane

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog is not working on tomcat however it is working on eclipse on same machine. Please suggest the resolution.

Comment: Why do you attempt to run Swing/GUI code on an application server? That makes no sense.

Comment: I need to create a tool and deploy it on the server so that the client can use it. In the tool I am using swing to display dialog boxes. Hence, I have to attempt to run Swing/GUI code on an application server. Please help.

Comment: Again, you can't run Swing code in an application server. Tomcat shows webpages not Swing. That's why they invented HTML. If you want to create a standalone tool use Swing, preferrably JavaFX. But then you don't need Tomcat for that. What does the architecture look like? What is the tool supposed to do?

Comment: Actually I have created a tool and I am running it on eclipse using the tomcat server. When I am running it on eclipse, I am getting the JOptionPane message dialog as well as the JFileChooser "Save As" Dialog. But, when I am deploying the war file of the tool in the tomcat/webapps folder and trying to access it, I am unable to get these dialog boxes. Please advise.

Comment: I will repeat it again for the last time: you can't run Swing code in an application server and expect the clients to see it. It works for you because the VM runs on your machine and Eclipse/Tomcat are stupid enough to allow any Swing code. The clients that connect see HTML only.